# If $w$ is an involution on an n-dimensional space, $det(w) = (-1)^r$ where $r$ is the rank of the map $i - w$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank, involutions

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page 109, it is asked that

> Let $w$ be a linear transformation of $E$ such that $w^2 = i$.Show
>   that $det (w) = (-1)^r$ where $r$ is the rank of the map $i - w$.

I thought since $w$ is an involution, it will map every element in the image to itself, so the map $i-w$ will only give map elements to nonzero image that are not mapped to itself in the first place.

However, after I couldn't move much, so how can I continue ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating a bit on Lord Shark's answer (+1). Also proffering a way to do this without using eigenvectors explicitly.

We can write any vector $v\in E$ as a sum (think: writing a function as a sum of its even and odd parts)
$$
v=\frac12(v+w(v))+\frac12(v-w(v)).\qquad(*)
$$
Here (the proof is an exercise) the former part belongs to the subspace
$$
E_1=\{x\in E\mid w(x)=x\}
$$
and the latter part belongs to the subspace
$$
E_2=\{x\in E\mid w(x)=-x\}.
$$
**Claim.** $E=E_1\oplus E_2.$

**Proof.** Clearly $E_1\cap E_2=\{0_E\}$, so the subspace sum $E_1+E_2$ is direct. By the decomposition $(*)$ the sum is all of $E$. QED

Clearly the linear transformation $i-w$ kills all of $E_1$, but it doubles all the elements of $E_2$. Therefore the rank of $i-w$ is equal to the dimension of $E_2$.

OTOH the direct sum decomposition means that we get a basis of $E$ as a union of bases for the subspaces $E_1$ and $E_2$. With respect to such a basis the matrix of $w$ has $+1$s along the diagonal while we are in $E_1$ and $-1$s while in $E_2$. The number of $-1$s is equal to $\dim E_2$. The claim follows.

Comment: I'm still reading the proof, but just a quick note, we never said that the space is a *real* vector space, so you cannot have such an expression like $\frac{1}{2}( v + w(v))$

Comment: I have just one problem which is about how the rank of $i-w$ is equal to the dimension of $E_2$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas You only need the ability to divide by two. The term  *linear transformation* implies that $E$ is a vector space over *some* field $K$. The recipe I gave works unless $K$ has characteristic two. But, how is it possible that you have not heard of eigenvalues, but have heard of fields other than the real numbers :-)

Comment: What is your definition of the rank of a linear transformation? For any vector $v\in E_2$ we have $(i-w)(v)=2v$ so the image of $i-w$ is equal to $E_2$.

Comment: :D, I'm studying _Abstract_ linear algebra and that subject is my next subject; however, it is not cover well in the book that I'm using. I mean their application or what they mean is not well explained, so neither I'm not able to use them for any proof, not can understand any proof that uses them :)

Comment: Got it by the way, thanks a lot. It is a nice proof.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are thinking about projection maps, those satisfying $w^2=w$,
not involutions, satisfying $w^2=I$. An involution is diagonalisable,
and its possible eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: I haven't studied eigenvalues, can you provide a more detailed proof ?